# How assign the name of a check box to a cell in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a check box in excel and I would like that when I click on the check box name be assigned to a cell in another sheet.

how can i do that?

Here is what I tried but I get an error 424

```
Private Sub checkbox1_click()
Worksheets("Produits").Range("A1") = checkbox1.Caption
End Sub
```

Ps: I use Office2019

Comment: First of all provide your attempts, second I think there were tons of similar topics here, just search for a while..

Comment: No subject on StackOverflow answers this question I spent hours on it unless I did not search well in which case please provide me with a link!

Comment: Your code will work for an ActiveX type of checkbox. It needs to be modified if it's a form control. Which type are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity I will assume that your checkbox is located in a worksheet named `Test` . I will also assume that when the checkbox is unchecked the corresponding cell should be emptied.

For an **ActiveX** type of checkbox, named `CheckBox1`, your code should be located in the same worksheet as the checkbox and should look like so:

```
Option Explicit
Sub CheckBox1_Click()

Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Produits")
If CheckBox1.Value Then
    sht.Range("A1") = CheckBox1.Caption
Else
    sht.Range("A1").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

For a **Form Control** type of checkbox, named `Check Box 2`, your code should be located in a module and should look like so:

```
Option Explicit

Sub CheckBox2_Click()
Dim cb As CheckBox
Dim sht1 As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet

Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")
Set sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Produits")

Set cb = sht1.CheckBoxes("Check Box 2") 'whatever the name of your checkbox is...

If cb.Value = 1 Then
    sht2.Range("A2") = cb.Caption
Else
    sht2.Range("A2").ClearContents
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot about .Value
Try something like that:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Range("A1").Value = CheckBox1.Caption
```

But I don't know what's the point about your case. Maybe you'll fined that way more helpful.

```
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Range("A1").Value = CheckBox1.Caption
End If

If CheckBox1.Value = False Then
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("YourSheet").Range("A1").ClearContents
End If
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested to me but I still got an error. I don't know if it's me who is doing something wrong or if it's because my Office 2019 is in French

Comment: I think you got something with your "checkbox1". Carefully check the name of the object.
Also do you using an ActivX checkbox or Form Controls ?